# /usr/bin/pass and /usr/bin/pass2

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, zsh

Trying to install `pass` (password manager).
I noticed that in my system (Ubuntu 14.04.4) another program called `pass` is already installed but I am sure that this is not password manager.
     `pass --help`     returns

```
Input format should be:
./pass inputfile min_window max_window false_num outputfile [-qnorm] [-nop] [-adjust] [-p priorfile]
```

I managed to find that this is possibly compiler, comes from packege `pass2` and may be a part of `binutils` but as a search phrase is short finding it in a web search is quite of pita... Any combinations of 'pass and linux' end with troubleshooting of installing `pass` in lfs...

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `dpkg -S` to search for what package owns the file:

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/pass
```

My guess, based solely on the names of the expected command line options, is that your `pass` command is a command line version of *Poisson Approximation for Statistical Significance* (a bioinformatics tool).  This tool has a web interface here (for example, there are others too): http://insilicom.com/root?tool_id=hgv_pass

Comment: Spot on. My Ubuntu is indeed Biolinux 8 flavour. Thanks!